# Split string by period but not if whitespace after period

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following and want to split the names into an array using the period character as a separator. Some names unfortunately also contain the period character which is causing an incorrect split. I cannot modify the character being used to separate the names.

```
"John Smith.John Mc. Smith.Jim Smith"
```

Desired output

```
 ["John Smith","John Mc. Smith","Jim Smith"]
```

The following regex works well in the editor
https://regex101.com/r/oK6iB8/32

But it does not work in the Chrome console

```
"John Smith.John Mc. Smith.Jim Smith".split('\.(?=\S)|:')
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NogQrQ?editors=1111

Incorrect output

```
["John Smith.John Mc. Smith.Jim Smith"]
```

Why is this working in the Regex editor but not in the Codepen snippet ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern.

`\.(?!\s)` - `.` should not be followed by `space` (negative lookahead)

```js
let str ="John Smith.John Mc. Smith.Jim Smith"

let op = str.split(/\.(?!\s)/g)

console.log(op)
```

> Why my code didn't worked

`split('\.(?=\S)|:')` because here you're giving `\.(?=\S)|:` as a `string` not as regular expression.

```js
console.log("John Smith.John Mc. Smith.Jim Smith".split(/\.(?=\S)|:/))
```